# How do I decrypt files that are encrypted using des command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, des

I need to decrypt files that are encrypted with this command:

```
des -E -u -k "some key" file.in file.out.enc
```

The decryption code in Ruby:

```
def decrypt(key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(‘des’).decrypt
  cipher.key = key

  File.open(‘file.out’, ‘wb’) do |outf|
    decrypted = cipher.update(File.read(‘file.in.enc’)) + cipher.final
    outf.write(decrypted)
  end
end
```

I’m getting wrong final block length error when I run the code above. I also tried decrypting using the openssl command line tool and got a bad magic number error. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the mode, from `CBC` to `ECB` for instance with `OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-ECB')`.

If you check which ciphers your Ruby installation supports by looking at `OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers`, you'll find a list of available modes too.